# PHP Mailer Doesn't Send All Fields

Tags: php, html, forms, form-submit

I am new to PHP and I am trying to create a PHP form field and I have four "Check Boxes" named Output1, Output2, Output3, and Output4 but when I select all four Check Boxes it only send me one and not all four values.

**NOTE** I have other fields on this from as well but I just wanted to provide you the HTML form info for Output.

**Here is the HTML:**

```
 <form id="surveyForm" class="form" action="mailsurvey.php" method="post" name="surveyForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return ValidateContactForm2();">
 <input id="Output1" type="checkbox" name="Output1" value="Isolated" />
 <input id="Output2" type="checkbox" name="Output2" value="Isolated" />
 <input id="Output3" type="checkbox" name="Output3" value="Isolated" />
 <input id="Output4" type="checkbox" name="Output4" value="Isolated" />
 </form>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
 <?php 

 require("includes/class.phpmailer.php");
 require("includes/class.smtp.php");
 require("includes/class.pop3.php");

 if($_FILES['headshot']['name']!="")
 {

 $imgtype=explode('.',$_FILES['headshot']['name']);
 $len=sizeof($imgtype);
 $image_file=uniqid().'.'.$imgtype[$len-1];

 $tmppath='uploads/';

 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['headshot']['tmp_name'],$tmppath.$image_file);
 $file_path=$tmppath.$image_file;
 }
 else
 {                
      $file_path="";
 }

 if($_FILES['bodyshot']['name']!="")
 {

      $imgtype=explode('.',$_FILES['bodyshot']['name']);
      $len=sizeof($imgtype);
      $image_file=uniqid().'.'.$imgtype[$len-1];

      $tmppath='uploads2/';

      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['bodyshot']['tmp_name'],$tmppath.$image_file);
      $file_path2=$tmppath.$image_file;
 }
 else
 {                
      $file_path2="";
 }


 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->Host = "localhost";
 $mail->Mailer = "smtp";

 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $company = $_POST['company'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $phone = $_POST['phone'];
 $comments = $_POST['Comments'];
 $totalpower = $_POST['Total_Power']." ".$_POST['Total_Power2']."           ".$_POST['Total_Power3']." ".$_POST['Total_Power4']." ".$_POST['Total_Power5'];
 $input = $_POST['Input']." ".$_POST['Input2']." ".$_POST['Input3']."      ".$_POST['Input4'];
 $strings = $_POST['Strings4']." ".$_POST['Strings3']." ".$_POST['Strings2']."      ".$_POST['Strings']; 
 $output = $_POST['Output1']." ".$_POST['Output2']." ".$_POST['Output3']."      ".$_POST['Output4'];
 $dimming = $_POST['Dimming4']." ".$_POST['Dimming3']." ".$_POST['Dimming2']."      ".$_POST['Dimming'];
 $packaging = $_POST['Packaging4']." ".$_POST['Packaging3']." ".$_POST['Packaging2']."      ".$_POST['Packaging'];

 $subject = "New Product Inquiry / Survey";
 $body = "Name: " .$name. "<br> ".
 "Company: " .$company. "<br>".
 "Phone: " .$phone."<br>".
 "Email: " .$email."<br><br><hr>".
 "Total Power: " .$totalpower."<br>".
 "Input: " .$input."<br>".
 "Strings: " .$strings."<br>".
 "Output: " .$output."<br>".
 "Dimming: " .$dimming."<br>".
 "Packaging: " .$packaging."<br>".
 "Comments: " .$comments."<br>"
 ;

 $mail->IsSMTP();
 $mail->From = 'support@domain.com';
 $mail->FromName = 'support@domain.com';
 $mail->Subject = "New Product Inquiry";
 $mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";                // optional, comment out and test

 if($file_path!="")
 {
 $mail->AddAttachment($file_path);
 }

 if($file_path2!="")
 {
      $mail->AddAttachment($file_path2);
 }

 $mail->MsgHTML($body);

 $mail->AddAddress('email@domain.com');

 if(!$mail->Send())
 {
      $msg = "Unable to send email";
 }
 else
 {
      $msg = header("location: thank-you2.php");
 }
 ?>
```

Can someone please tell me why this form will not send **ALL** Output Fields if a user selects all four boxes. If you have any questions please let me know.

Thanks,

Frank

Comment: IDs have to be unique, you can't use `id="Output1"` for all the checkboxes.

Comment: Barmar I updated my posting and changed the ID's to be unique but the form still doesn't send me all the data for the Output field. I only get one value from all four boxes. Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't expect that to fix it, that's why it's a comment, not an answer. I can't see any reason why you're only getting one checkbox, you should get all the ones that are checked. Can add the output of `var_dump($_POST)` to the question? Could the validation function be changing them?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my problem was and the reason why I wanted to post this answer for others to be aware of.

My problem was I was working on the wrong PHP file. I have two of the same PHP files in my site one was burred under a couple folders and one was at the root of the site. The one burred was the one I should have been working on making changes to because that was the LIVE file. While I was uploading a file that wasn't working because it was the wrong one. I figured that out by double check the path in the form element of the form page.

```
<form id="surveyForm" class="form" **action="subfolder/formmailer_scripts/mailsurvey.php"** method="post" name="surveyForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return ValidateContactForm2();">
```

So the morel of the story is pay attention and make sure you don't over look the simple things. I wasted about an hour on this reuploading a file that wasn't were it need to be. Hope this helps others!